# How to get application root directory in visualstudio postbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013

ll the solutions , how can i get the path of that text file in postbuild event using macros,  as i have different folder structure for different solutions ,So can't fetch the text file value by using $(SolutionDir) macro

Comment: Let me explain it properly,
I have one application folder where many Visualstudio solutions are there with different folder hirerchy , I want to keep one text file  in application root which will be used by all the solutions , how can i get the path of that text file in postbuild event using macros, 
as i have different folder structure for different solutions ,So can't fetch the text file value by using $(SolutionDir) macro